# Type Mismatch error when items in Inbox declared as mailitems

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following VBA code in Outlook to move mail to a personal folder if it is old.  Here is the code:

I get an exception on the line Next objItem (looking at the watch it is set to nothing).

What would cause objItem to be null and thus cause a **Type Mismatch** exception in the **Next objItem** line?

```
Sub MoveOldMailFromInbox()

Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, objItem As Outlook.MailItem, mail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Set Inbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim mailToMove As New Collection

Dim EightyFiveDaysAgo As Date
EightyFiveDaysAgo = DateAdd("d", -85, Date)

Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("PersonalFolders").Folders("InboxOlderThan85Days")
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
End If

For Each objItem In Inbox.Items
    If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then

        If objItem.Class = olMail And objItem.ReceivedTime < EightyFiveDaysAgo Then

            mailToMove.Add objItem

        End If
    End If
Next objItem


For Each mail In mailToMove
    mail.UnRead = False
    mail.Move objFolder
Next mail

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what would be a better way?  Is there a way to define it as a generic item and then check if its a mailItem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating through `Inbox.Items` but your variable `objItem` is defined as `MailItem` - an item in your inbox might not always be a MailItem.

Try

```
Dim objItem as Object
```